# System.FormatException if use new CultureInfo("id-ID") - Indonesian culture

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert exponential value to decimal with Indonesian culture but it does not work..

```
string _ex = "1.2162876E-5";
decimal _dec = decimal.Parse(_ex, NumberStyles.Float, new CultureInfo("id-ID"));
```

it thrown me System.FormatException

[image: p]

but it works properly if I use en-US
decimal d0 = decimal.Parse(_ex, NumberStyles.Float, new CultureInfo("en-US"));

what I missed?

please help

thanks a lot
Don2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `id-ID`, the decimal separator (`CultureInfo.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator`) is `","`, so it is expecting `"1,2162876E-5"` as the input (meaning the numeric value zero point zero zero zero zero one two etc). If the input is using a `"."` to mean decimal point, then you should probably use the invariant culture to parse it (`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`), instead of a locale-specific culture.